# Input validation message not disappearing

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I've got a form that validate input fields, both textboxes and radio buttons. When trying to submit the form and the fields have not been completed, the validation error messages displays correctly. When a field has the the required data it needs the validation error should disappear immediately. The validation messages disappears on the textboxes when the user types. However, when selecting an option on the radio button the validaton message (or the background colour of that field) does not dissapear.

This is what it looks like before selecting:

[image]

And this is after a selection was made:

[image]

My code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-12 control-label label-input">
            Is this also your residence address?
            <a tabindex="-1" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" class="popover-dismiss" rel="popover" data-content="We may need to send some policy and claim documents to you via mail.">
                <img src="~/Images/svg/Icon Info.svg" height="16" width="16" />
            </a>
        </label>
        @*@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address.RiskIsResidence, new {@class = "col-lg-12 control-label label-input"})*@
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-radio">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Address.RiskIsResidence, "Yes", new { name = "radIsResidence" }) Yes
                </label>

                <label class="btn btn-radio">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Address.RiskIsResidence, "No", new { name = "radIsResidence" }) No
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address.RiskIsResidence, null, new { @class = "col-lg-12" })
    </div>
```

My CSS for the validation:

```
    .field-validation-error, .validation-summary-errors,
     label.error {
     color: #fff;
     background-color:#ef425e;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-family: "Open Sans";
     font-style: normal;
     font-stretch: normal;
     line-height: normal;
     letter-spacing: normal;
     padding:8px 10px;
     margin:3px 0;
     width:100%;
     display:inline-block;
     }

     .input-validation-error, input-validation-errors,
     input.error {
     border: 2px solid #ef425e;
     padding:7px;
     }

    .input-validation-error:focus {
     border: 1px solid #ef425e;
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     padding:7px;
     /*box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 0 red;*/
     }
```

How would I remove the colour or make it disappear when selecting a radio button? Preferably I would like to do this in css as this is across all page.

---

### UPDATE

The validation used are jquery-validate, this is included in the bundle config which handles the validation (Enitity framework used thus required set in model).

The custom javascript that was used to remove the html error message in the validation control was removed as below, however I found that removing the class is not working, thus the red strip is still displaying.

```
    $('input[type=radio]').on("change", function (e) {
    //$(this).trigger('reset.unobtrusiveValidation');
    $(this).closest('div.form-group').find(".field-validation-error").html("");
    $(this).closest('div.form-group').find(".field-validation-error").remove();

});
```

How do I remove a class through JS?

Comment: Can you please also post the error elements and how the above classes are attached to them when form is validated?

Comment: @jom, I updated the question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for error box is stil visible, after you remove the content of it, is because you added `padding: 7px`, and therefore the element will always be visible.

So in order to remove the class and therefor the styling, you could do this.

```
$(this).closest('div.form-group').find(".field-validation-error").removeClass("field-validation-error")
```

but this means you will not be able to add content to it again, if the user change the value to an incorrect value, because you remove the class.
So instead you should add a class like errorHide, and then us this to toggle the styling of your element.

Use .errorHide to to specify when the stylling should be added

```
.field-validation-error.errorShow.errorHide{
    display:none;
}
```

And then you can toggle it with jquery, and make sure, it's only visible when you need it to be.

```
$(this).closest('div.form-group').find(".field-validation-error").toggleClass( "errorHide" )
```